# Thought process behind determining if binary tree is symmetric

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

Here is the problem description:

Given a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (ie, symmetric around its center).

For example, this binary tree [1,2,2,3,4,4,3] is symmetric:

```
    1
   / \
  2   2
 / \ / \
3  4 4  3
```

But the following [1,2,2,null,3,null,3] is not:

```
    1
   / \
  2   2
   \   \
   3    3
```

Sourced from: [Determine if tree is symmetric](https://leetcode.com/problems/symmetric-tree/description/)

I took a lot of time to solve the problem and the solution I came up with was to do a level order traversal and check that the values in each level are a palindrome. This implementation passed the tests on leetcode. However, when I read the editorial, I saw an extremely short recursive program and I have been having trouble getting my head around it.

```
public boolean isSymmetric(TreeNode root) {
    return isMirror(root, root); }

public boolean isMirror(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
    if (t1 == null && t2 == null) return true;
    if (t1 == null || t2 == null) return false;
    return (t1.val == t2.val)
        && isMirror(t1.right, t2.left)
        && isMirror(t1.left, t2.right);}
```

1. How can one prove the correctness of the above recursive version? (I guess this can be proved inductively?)
2. Can someone outline the thought process in coming up with such a solution. Do you verify the solution by actually visualizing the call stack or is there a good high level thinking framework to reason about such problems?

I understand that tree is a recursive data structure in itself i.e. composed of left and right subtree that follow the same structure but for some reason when I try to verify the validity of this solution, I attempt to visualize recursive calls and eventually my thoughts get entangled. [This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8t4KCaDB108) has done a good job at explaining how the call stack unrolls as recursion proceeds but I just wanted to improve my thought process for such "easy" recursive problems and hence am posting here.

(FWIW, I am familiar with recursion/DFS/backtracking and how the call flow is but still I was stuck coming up and validating the high level recursive idea for the above problem)

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the solution which can be done with a slick recursive algorithm. The idea is to maintain two references point to the root initially and then move one sub tree to the left and the other sub tree to the opposite direction and the reverse the direction of traversal for both the children to now have then point to symmetric node on either sub trees(if it exists)

Here `t1` and `t2` refers to the left and right sub tree.

```
 if (t1 == null || t2 == null) return false;
```

What this step does is to check if there exist both a right and left sub tree because in case we do not have either one subtree then it can't be symmetric so we return `false`

```
 if (t1 == null && t2 == null) return true;
```

This accounts for leaf nodes where it is okay to have null as left and right child tree.  So we return true;

```
return (t1.val == t2.val)
        && isMirror(t1.right, t2.left)
        && isMirror(t1.left, t2.right);}
```

can be re written as

```
 if(t1.val != t2.val) return false;
 auto left =  isMirror(t1.right, t2.left)
 auto right = isMirror(t1.left, t2.right);
 return left && right
```

Now that we know that both the sub tree are valid (i.e not null) we then check for their value to check if they are the same. If not same we can return false as there is no point in looking further.

The reason why we can compare is because since we know it has to be a complete binary tree to be symmetric we can move the left sub tree(t1) to the left and right sub tree(t2) to the right to move the the symmetric node on the right sub tree.

```
                        1 (t1, t2)
                      /  \
                     2    2
                    / \  / \
                   4  5  5  4
```

After `isMirror(t1.right, t2.left)`

```
                        1 
                      /  \
                (t2) 2    2(t1)
                    / \  / \
                   4  5  5  4
```

After calling `isMirror(t1.right, t2.left)` recursively again

```
                        1 
                      /  \
                     2    2
                    / \  / \
              (t2) 4  5  5  4(t1)
```

Now this will in turn call it's child nodes only to return true as they are both null. Then the value of `t1` and `t2` is checked and returns `true` or `false`. And then `isMirror(t1.left, t2.right)` is called now to reach here.

```
                       1 
                     /   \
                    2     2
                   / \    / \
                  4  5   5  4
                    (t2)(t1)
```

Which now does the same as the above step and unrolls the call stack.

So at stack frame we have `left` indicating if the left sub tree of `t1` is symmetric to the right sub tree of `t2` and `right` indicating the opposite.

Since we have already checked if `t1.val` equal `t2.val`  before recursively checking for it's children, we know that the root is equal and if it's children are equal so we return `return left && right` the sub tree of `t1` is symmetric to sub tree of `t2`

If this gets a bit convoluted you can trace it out on a papare and check it might clear things up a lot better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks thebenman for the call stack visualization. After seeing the solution, I could trace it out but it would help to figure out a way to reason about the correctness of the algorithm without actually simulating it. In that direction, would you happen to know how the recursive version can be proved correct?

Answer (score 0):

> How can one prove the correctness of the above recursive version? (I
>   guess this can be proved inductively?)

Yes, you can prove it by induction.

> Can someone outline the thought process in coming up with such a
>   solution. Do you verify the solution by actually visualizing the call
>   stack or is there a good high level thinking framework to reason about
>   such problems?

I solved the problem in both way - level order traversal and recursion. By seeing this problem, my first thought was to use level order traversal. And there is no shame on thinking sub-optimal solution (with extra space) at first attempt. Then I figured out the recursive approach.

I think this is all about practice. The more recursion problem you solve, the more you start to think/visualize in the head the corresponding recursion tree. At the beginning, I struggled with it and use the help of debugger to see the contents of function stack in each call. But debugging is time consuming and you can't find scope to debug in whiteboard coding. Now at my level, I can figure out easy/medium recursion problem by seeing it in head and hard one by simulating in pen & paper/whiteboard.

These things will improve with experience and more practice. Experience with certain data-structure matters - The person who see and solve a lot of binary tree(pointer representation)/BST problem will more likely to outperform here than the person who can deal recursion very good but didn't solve binary tree problem that much.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "there is no shame on thinking sub-optimal solution (with extra space) at first attempt." Thanks that is encouraging. Could you sketch out the inductive proof as to why the recursive algorithm is correct?